# Button_click event(in code) for every button in multiple GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple `groupbox`, which one contains a question and some answers and `button` ANSWER in each `GroupBox`.  I create `GroupBox` and its Controls in Form_Load Method, not manually. How to handle `button_click` events for every `button`? I think it's not necessary to write this handle method for every `button`, because there are only two different button_handler: for questions where there can be only one correct answers, and for questions, where multiple answers can be correct.
My questions look like:

My GroupBox structure:

```
int loc = 20;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
                gb.Name = "GroupBox" + (i + 1);
                gb.Size = new Size(500, 200);
                gb.Location = new Point(40, loc);
                gb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;

                Label q_text = new Label(); // текст питання
                q_text.Name = "label" + (i + 1);
                q_text.Text = "Питання" + (i + 1);
                q_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                q_text.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                gb.Controls.Add(q_text);
                int iter = q_text.Location.Y + 30;
                if (i <= 5)
                {
                    foreach (string key in questions[i].answers.Keys)
                    {
                        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                        rb.Text = key;
                        rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
                        rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                        iter += 30;
                        gb.Controls.Add(rb);
                    }
                }else
                    if (i > 5)
                    {
                        foreach (string key in questions[i].answers.Keys)
                        {
                            CheckBox rb = new CheckBox();
                            rb.Text = key;
                            rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
                            rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                            iter += 30;
                            gb.Controls.Add(rb);
                        }

                    }


                Button b = new Button();
                b.Name = "button" + (i + 1);
                b.Text = "Answer";
                b.Location = new Point(gb.Size.Width - 120, gb.Size.Height - 30);
                gb.Controls.Add(b);
                this.Controls.Add(gb);
                loc += 200;
            }
```

Comment: I updated my post with GroupBox structure. But I change my mind about it. I just create one button atthe end of form, somethind like: "Submit all and Finish". But can't place this button at the end of form. Can you know to do it in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general click event for your buttons:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Name = "button" + (i + 1).ToString();
b.Click += b_Click;
```

and in the method, examine the sender to see which button was clicked:

```
void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button b = sender as Button;
  if (b != null) {
    GroupBox gp = b.Parent as GroupBox;
    int bIndex = Convert.ToInt32(b.Name.Substring(6)) - 1;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("I'm clicking {0}, question index #{1}",
                    gp.Name, bIndex));        
  }
}
```

After that, you would have to examine the checked values of your GroupBox child controls with the allowable answers in the `questions[bIndex].answers` variable.