# How to undo Button_Click Events (Windows Phone App)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is what I have:

1. Screen with multiple buttons (16)
2. Each Button is transparent (so no background image, colour etc)
3. On click each button gets an image  using

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (MediaButton.Content == FindResource("Play"))
       {
           MediaButton.Content = FindResource("Stop");
       }
       else
       {
           MediaButton.Content = FindResource("Play");
       }
   }
   ```

What I need:
1. At the end of the task, I need the user to press a different button which will then reset the screen. So all Button Background Images should "disapear" and the buttons should be transparent again.

Anyone, any idea how I can do that? Would it be something "simple" as in MediaButton.Content="", which means empty?

Any feedback/help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried it? Your suggestion sounds like the first thing I'd try as well. Maybe not `""` but `null`. But otherwise, plausible.

Comment: guess what... I havent tried it yet :-). Didnt think that it was that "simple" :-), so I just need to create a sorta loop like the one here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182816/button-click-eventin-code-for-every-button-in-multiple-groupbox) and add MediaButton.Content=Null in the Click Event?

Comment: I mean this without any offense, but you're always better off trying your ideas first :) The SO users in general will be more accepting of your questions (no effort in trying, no effort in answering), and you learn **a lot** of things. It's an overused cliché, but finding out for yourself helps you both in understanding the issue better, and remembering that it did or didn't work.

Comment: And to answer your question, either make sure you have a list of the items you want to reset, or find out how to find all items you want :)

Comment: hahaha.... and you are absolutely correct :-). Trying is always better than asking... its just that I have spend the last couple of days with "little" issues that I thought were simple to do but in the end realized that my way of thinking just doesnt work with c#. Hence, I asked first. But again, you are right and no offense taken :-). I will test and let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help :-). I have changed my approach and no longer need to reset all Click Even Handlers. However, I am now facing a different issue which I have posted as well (and this time I tested a lot... ;-)). do you mind having a look at it and see if you would have any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404787/sound-disabled-after-changing-background-image